# Creating Java object with boost::posix_time::ptime serialized XML representation

Tags: java, c++, xml, serialization, boost

I have following XML generated by serializing a boost::posix_time::ptime structure. I want to create a Java Date object with this XML.

```
<timeStamp class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <ptime_date class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <date>20100119</date>
    </ptime_date>
    <ptime_time_duration class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <time_duration_hours>11</time_duration_hours>
        <time_duration_minutes>53</time_duration_minutes>
        <time_duration_seconds>33</time_duration_seconds>
        <time_duration_fractional_seconds>0</time_duration_fractional_seconds>
    </ptime_time_duration>
</timeStamp>
```

Below is the Java code that is supposed to construct Date object by de-serializing this XML. Problem that I am facing is how to break the <date> tag into year/month/day sequence.

```
Integer date = timeStamp.getPtimeDate().getDate();
Integer hrs = timeStamp.getPtimeTimeDuration().getTimeDurationHours();
Integer mins = timeStamp.getPtimeTimeDuration().getTimeDurationMinutes();
Integer secs = timeStamp.getPtimeTimeDuration().getTimeDurationSeconds();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//TODO
//cal.set(year, month, day, hrs, mins, secs);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Any hints?

> EDIT:

I am looking for some elegant solution that doesn't require converting date to a string and then splitting it. That would be my last resort.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't want to use a `String` (though I urge you to reconsider, after all that's what it is and easier to parse too), I guess you can do regular old division to extract parts. i.e.

```
int tmp = date; // unboxing
int year = tmp / 10000;
int month = (tmp % 10000) / 100;
int day = tmp % 100;
```

That's not very elegant either.

The best way to handle this would be to instruct whatever you're using to deserialize to give you back a `String` for `date` instead of an `Integer`. Then you can just take the first four characters for your, next two for month and last two for day. [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can do the heavy lifting here.

Comment: I went on with the subString() approach after all as it is easier to read than the modulus division method.